# Nodejs - SSL Handshake logs

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am trying to debug cert issue in my node module which is running in kubernetes.

The node app is running as below. It is enabled with SSL.

```
node --max-old-space-size=2560 ./server/index.js
```

How can I enable the SSL handshake trace?
 For Java app, `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`

Is there any equivalent for node app?

Comment: NODE_DEBUG='https,tls' node --max-old-space-size=2560 ./server/index.js

Comment: This is not working.